# Argument of type 'Post' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'

Tags: angular

I have a problem where I made a model and I still can't import things from that model, such as title and content. Here's the code:

posts.ts (model)

```
export class Post {
  "title": String;
  "content": String;
}
```

And this is my post-create.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as EventEmitter from 'events';
import { Post } from '../../posts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css'],
})
export class PostCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  enteredTitle: String = '';
  enteredContent: String = '';
  postCreated = new EventEmitter();
  post: Post;
  constructor() {}

  onAddPost() {
    this.post = { title: this.enteredTitle, content: this.enteredContent };
    this.postCreated.emit(this.post);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Model class should be like below

```
export class Post {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}

// also component variables

 enteredTitle: string = '';
 enteredContent: string = '';
```

Hope this should resolve your issue. Also check your Model import statement.

Comment: are you getting any compilation error for model import..?

Comment: It's all working for now, thank you my friend